# PayPal SDK: PayPal error: Could not find endpoint for live.dyson

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I'm using the PayPal 2.0 SDK for Iphone. at the "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox" or "PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork" it's all works perfect.

But when changing to "PayPalEnvironmentProduction" I get this very strange error, witch i can not find any documentary about what it actually means..

**PayPal SDK: PayPal error: Could not find endpoint for live.dyson**

My code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

 [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : kPayPalClientId}];
}
```

At "PayCalssVC":

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
}


-(void)payPressed
{
 NSDecimalNumber *amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[User getLoggedInUser].priceOfNewTone];


    PayPalPayment *payMant = [[PayPalPayment alloc]init];
    payMant.amount = amount;
    payMant.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentSale;
    payMant.currencyCode = @"ILS";
    payMant.shortDescription = @"Song Distribution";

    if (!payMant.processable) {

    }

    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payMant
                                                                                                configuration:_payPalConfig
                                                                                                     delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

My payClint ID is live, and the error occurs when this is called:

```
 [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@PiratM, that warning message was misleading, and should not have appeared. Please ignore it. (It won't be present after our next update to the SDK.)